# Cannot find added elements in Tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android

I created a *Tabbed Activity* template project using Android Studio. 
Then I created a LinearLayout with a nested TextView on it:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/updateView"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="707dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/updateTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This view is shown on preview, but there's none of it in the built app.

When I try to get a reference to it from my code:

```
LinearLayout lastUpdate = findViewById(R.id.updateView)
```

I get null in runtime.
So, how can I modify the code?

[Preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZZB0.png)

Comment: Can you post full activity.java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving xml code of LinearLayout upper, than code of AppBarLayout, and modification of dynamic pixels (dp) of ViewPager and my textView